Use of GROUPING_ID tabular OLAP in BI tools such as Power BI
I am trying to figure out (actually I am forgetting), how GROUPING_ID function from Tabular OLAP can be used in BI frontend tools, such as Power BI. I used it back in time once in BOXI.
Background: I generated a CUBE table using Redshift Group By extention. But I think other databases also provide the same functions. With that, I have a got a table with all pre-computed levels of aggregations, and I also kept a column generated by GROUPING_ID function.
I can see that for each grouping set (64 actually, the maximum supported) I have got a GROUPING_ID output, so this give me the idea that it can be used in frontend tool like Power BI as some sort of a filter or grouping concept.
Question:
I am missing out on the detail how exactly should this information be used. In our case, we have 64 grouping sets, generated from 5 dimensional keys. Output of Grouping ID is 64 various different numbers, ranging from 0 to 63

